# get image url from SharePoint genericlist with CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to get the image url from a list but dont now how. the usual search on google didnt help. This is my code so far:

```
         using(var context = MySession.Current.spcontext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            List<Produkt> produkter = new List<Produkt>();
            ListItemCollection listFromSharePoint = _foodRepo.RetriveList(context, PRODUKTER);
            foreach(ListItem items in listFromSharePoint)
            {
                Produkt oneItem = new Produkt();

                oneItem.bild = (string)items["Bild"];  <--Column name is "Bild" but how to get the url?
                produkter.Add(oneItem);
            }
            ViewBag.Produkter = produkter;
        }
```

image of what I want:

[image]

everything loads from sharepoint, but dont know how to reach the url. any ideas?

Comment: Do you call `ctx.Load(items); ctx.ExecuteQuery();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the itemvalues, they are always an object which has to be casted to the correct class:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    List list = web.Lists.GetById(listId);
    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
    ctx.Load(item);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    FieldUrlValue fieldValue = (FieldUrlValue)item["Bild"]; //<-- casting!
    string bildUrl = fieldValue.Url; //<-- here you can access the values
}
```

Comment: I actually solved this one a while back.. But thank you very much for your solution.